# Npm installed in npm global?

Tags: npm

So I'm trying to see what npm packages I have installed globally using this command,

```
 $ npm list -g --depth=0
```

and I see this,

```
/usr/local/lib
├── npm@5.5.1
```

Is npm installed as a package under npm itself? Or did I screw up somewhere and caused some kinda inception installation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `npm ls` command to view all the npm packages in your local system